# Why does flooring infinity not throw some error?

Tags: haskell, floating-point, infinity, floor

I found myself having a case where the equivalent of `floor $ 1/0` was being executed.

```hs
λ> 1/0
Infinity
```

This is normal behavior as far as I understand but, when `Infinity` is `floor`'d or `ceiling`'d

```hs
λ> floor $ 1/0   
179769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536021120113879871393357658789768814416622492847430639474124377767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913110540827237163350510684586298239947245938479716304835356329624224137216
```

Instead of failing, this very big number is produced. ***Why?***

Maybe more importantly, how can I distinguish this from a non faulty result without using a filter before applying another function?

Comment: the number appears to be `2^1024 :: Integer`, I don't know why that number in particular though.

Comment: Because someone forgot to test for infinity in the code for `properFraction`.

Comment: @Wes Well, Infinity is represented by 2 ^ 1023 in the IEEE 754 standard. It might have something to do with it.

Comment: @augustss The Haskell language report does not specify the behavior when passing `Infinite` to `properFraction`. Specifically at §6.4.6 it states "The function `properFraction` **takes a real fractional number** x and returns...". `Infinite` is not a number. So no, nobody forgot to test for infinity. The behavior is simply undefined in the language report (you should test for infinity yourself).

Comment: @Jefffrey, isn't a "real fractional number" just any member of a type in class `RealFrac`?

Comment: Like augustss said, is it possible that the spec simply forgot that use case?.

Comment: @Jeffrey I didn't just make up what happened, I know what happened.  When Haskell was first defined IEEE-754 floating point was not dominant like it is now, so there was no concern or thought about infinities or NaN.  I wrote the first implementation (that I know of) of `properFraction` for `Float` and `Double` and I forgot to test for infinity.  And subsequent re-implementations have repeated the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first question is perhaps not so important, so I'll try to answer the second question first.

Once you have a number, if you know that it came from `floor x`, you can't know whether `x` was the valid representation of `2^1024` or if it was infinity. You can probably assume anything outside of the range of double is invalid and was produced from infinity, negative infinity, NaN or the like. It would be quite simple to check if your value is valid using one/many of the functions in `RealFloat`, like `isNaN`, `isInfinite`, etc.

You could also use something like `data Number a = N a | PosInf | NegInf`. Then you write:

```
instance RealFrac a => RealFrac (Number a) where 
  ...
  floor (N n) = floor n
  floor PosInf = error "Floor of positive infinity"
  floor NegInf = error "Floor of negative infinity"
  ..
```

Which approach is best is based mostly on your use case.

Maybe it would be correct for `floor (1/0)` to be an error. But the value is garbage anyways. Is it better to deal with garbage or an error?

But why `2^1024`? I took a look at the source for `GHC.Float`:

```
properFraction (F# x#)
  = case decodeFloat_Int# x# of
    (# m#, n# #) ->
        let m = I# m#
            n = I# n#
        in
        if n >= 0
        then (fromIntegral m * (2 ^ n), 0.0)
        else let i = if m >= 0 then                m `shiftR` negate n
                               else negate (negate m `shiftR` negate n)
                 f = m - (i `shiftL` negate n)
             in (fromIntegral i, encodeFloat (fromIntegral f) n)

floor x     = case properFraction x of
                (n,r) -> if r < 0.0 then n - 1 else n
```

Note that `decodeFloat_Int#` returns the mantissa and exponent. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Positive_and_negative_infinity):

> Positive and negative infinity are represented thus: sign = 0 for
>   positive infinity, 1 for negative infinity. biased exponent = all 1
>   bits. fraction = all 0 bits.

For `Float`, this means a base of 2^23, since there are 23 bits in the base, and an exponent of 105 (why 105? I actually have no idea. I would think it should be 255 - 127 = 128, but it seems to actually be 128 - 23). The value of `floor` is `fromIntegral m * (2 ^ n)` or `base*(2^exponent) == 2^23 * 2^105 == 2^128`. For double this value is 1024.

Comment: This isn't really relevant, but why on Earth does `properFraction` unbox its argument, decompose it, and then box up the pieces again before actually using them? I'm staring at that code and wondering how it makes any sense at all.

Comment: Beyond that, what's up with `shiftR m (negate n)`? The documentation gives no guarantee whatsoever of the result of that shift if `negate n` is large. If GHC is going to rely on weird undocumented behavior like that, why not use an explicitly unsafe shift?